# Plus-minus sign in the continued fraction

Tags: math-mode

[image: Continued fraction]

How to write the plus/minus signs aligned with the bottom of the fraction. I can write the rest of the part of equation (1.1) and (1.2). but can cot write the plus/minus sign at the bottom.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please help us to help you and add a **full** [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with \documentclass{...} and ending with \end{document}. Is easier for us in this way can help you copiyng and running code instead watch a screenshot.

Comment: no no. I have written this code: \[a_0+\frac{b_1}{a_1}_+\frac{b_2}{a_2}\]So I am not getting desirable space in plus sign between two fraction.

Comment: Duplicate of [How to write a + symbol which has been lowered down](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/623060/how-to-write-a-symbol-which-has-been-lowered-down) (although that one is newer, it has more votes)

Answer (score 10):

Here are two options:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\subplus}{\mathbin{\genfrac{}{}{0pt}{}{}{+}}}
\newcommand{\subminus}{\mathbin{\genfrac{}{}{0pt}{}{}{-}}}
\newcommand{\subcdots}{\genfrac{}{}{0pt}{}{}{\cdots}}
\begin{document}

Option 1:
\[
  1 - \begin{array}{@{}*{8}{c@{}}}
    1 &       & 1 &       & 1 &       & 1 \\ \cline{1-1}\cline{3-3}\cline{5-5}\cline{7-7}
    1 & {}+{} & 1 & {}-{} & 1 & {}+{} & 1 & {}- \cdots
  \end{array} =
  \frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2}
\]

Option 2:
\[
  1 - \frac{1}{1} \subplus \frac{1}{1} \subminus \frac{1}{1} \subplus \frac{1}{1} \subminus \subcdots =
  \frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2}
\]

\end{document}
```

Option 1 sets the fraction as an `array`, using `\cline` to simulate the fraction lines. Option 2 uses [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) to set a fraction with `0pt` horizontal rule. Additional macros have been created to set these using `\subplus`, `\subminus` and `\subcdots`.

Comment: ...I prefer Option 2.