# How to write a + symbol which has been lowered down

Tags: math-mode, symbols

I am trying to write a continued fraction in the style in the image provided. This involves lowering the + symbol to be on the same part of the page as the denominators of the fraction, but I am not sure how to do this. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

[image: Image of lowered down addition signs]

Comment: Link to somewhat related question: [amsmath - In math mode, how do I make the fraction bar "invisible"? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/589142/in-math-mode-how-do-i-make-the-fraction-bar-invisible)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `{\atop +}` to lower the `+`

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$a_1+\frac{1}{a_2} {\atop +} \frac{1}{a_3} {\atop +\ \cdots\ +}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

EDIT: As @David Carlisle suggested you could also use `\genfrac{}{}{0pt}{}{}{+}` from `amsmath` and get the same result without using a TeX primitive.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$a_1+\frac{1}{a_2} \genfrac{}{}{0pt}{}{}{+} \frac{1}{a_3} \genfrac{}{}{0pt}{}{}{+\ \cdots\ +}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: yes although `amsmath` will scream at you for the tex-primitive syntax `Package amsmath Warning: Foreign command \atop;`  so better to use `\genfrac` I think.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks! I hadn't known about `\genfrac`. I edited in the `\genfrac` equivalent to the answer.

Comment: thanks +1......

Answer (score 3):

Using `amsmath` to include `\text{...}` to `\raisebox{...}{$+$}` by `-1.5ex` or a suitable depth

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\lp}{\text{\raisebox{-1.5ex}{$\,+\,$}}}
\newcommand{\ls}[1]{\text{\raisebox{-1.5ex}{#1}}}

\begin{document}
  \[
    a_1 + 
    \frac{1}{a_2} \lp 
    \frac{1}{a_3} \lp 
    \frac{1}{a_3} \lp 
    \ls{$\,\cdots\,$} \lp
    \frac{1}{a_n}  
  \]
\end{document}
```

to get something like this...

[image: img]